# Aligning the title of bar chart in JqPlot

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am creating a bar chart using JQPlot.

Now I want to align the title of the barchart to the left of the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Found this at [here:](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jqplot-users/GDZW4BsDMiA)

No plans to extend the exiting renderer right now, sorry.  There would be a few steps involved to position it inside, correctly size the grid without title on top, and make sure legend and x2axis (if present) move to the proper location.

As a quick fix, you can make your own title and position it inside of the grid.  Something like:

```
mytitle = $('<div class="my-jqplot-title" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;padding-top: 15px;width:100%">My Custom Chart Title</div>').insertAfter('.jqplot-grid-canvas');
```

Inserting the element after the grid canvas is important so it doesn't get covered up by the grid.  It also needs to be before the event canvas, so events will be captured.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it:

**1st**: Just update the jquery.jqplot.css
Search for **.jqplot-title** and add alignment like:

```
text-align: right !important;
```

**2nd**: You can update the values generated by the main jqplot js (**jquery.jqplot.js** or **jquery.jqplot.min.js**).

Then try to search **jqplot-title**
scan the code and you may find like :

```
 styles['textAlign'] = 'center';
```

Default alignment is "center".
Then you can change the value like center/right.

You can also add some custome css inside the function by adding like etc.:

```
this._elem.css("padding-left", "10px");
```

**Tip**: The main function is **$.jqplot.DivTitleRenderer.prototype.draw**

Hope it helps!